# Keras VS Tensorflow for developing CNN or RNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am going to start a Deep learning project on image processing hopefully it would be CNN problem as we know Tensorflow and Keras both are very good frameworks to work on any deep learning problem. I am familiar with both of them and had coded in both but i want to identify the reasons (if any) which leads a deep learning project to a specific frame work.

Comment: We already have a documentation, where the frameworks are explained. This question provides only biased answers and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Have in mind that **`Keras` can actually run on Tensorflow** if you configure in such way. Keras also supporst `Theano` as a [backend](https://keras.io/backend/).

When you configure your installation, you include in your `keras.json` file what backend you wish to use (after you have installed it properly). In case you wish to use `Tensorflow` as backend your configuration file should look something like:

```
{
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

**Keras provides an abstraction** to Tensorflow's (or your selected backend)  functions and framework, *possibly* making it easier to learn and write, so you could try focusing on Keras first, and if it does not fit your need migrate to use Tensorflow direcly.

There is no unbiased or absolute answer regarding which one you should use, so trying them to see which one is a better fit could work out for you.